# jquery prototype conflict only in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs, conflict

I'm using jQuery to build a module for an existing page. The page uses also prototype, so there is the usual jQuery-prototype conflict. I'm using the jQuery.noConflict() and everything works fine in all browsers except  for ie (tested in ie8).
I've read all similar questions in here and other sites, but i can't get it to work.
This is about how it works: the page loads prototype and other .js files using prototype (effects.js, prototip.js etc) and then loads my module (aka jQuery is loaded after prototype).
I read about changing the prototype's $() function to $$$(), but this is impossible (many other modules using prototype will then need to be changed), so it's only about changing my js.

Then i read about using

```
(function($) {
    //my jQuery code in here

})(jQuery);
```

but i don't completely understand it. My code is about like this:

```
$J = jQuery.noConflict();
$J(document).ready(function(){
     fun1();
     //jquery stuff
     fun2();
});

function fun1(){
     //stuff/jQuery code/ call other functions
}

function fun2(){
     //stuff/jQuery code/ call other functions
}
```

if i put all the above into `(function($) { /*all the above*/})(jQuery);`

i get that all functions are undefined.

What am i doing wrong? Or is there another solution?

Comment: I would strongly suggest attempting to use one or the other, but not both. You can make them not conflict without too much trouble, but it means your user having to load two different libraries. There are plugins for both jQuery and Prototype which will do most things you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `jQuery.noConflict();` to work it must be called before all other javascript libraries are loaded to work otherwise you'll have already overwritten the `$` variable. The error you are getting with `(function($) { /*all the above*/})(jQuery);` is because this is defining an anonymous function, any function within this only exist within it and cannot be used outside of it, unless it is part of an object outside the scope of the anonymous function.

So you would need to use it like this.

```
//Must be called before any other library in included on the page.
$J = jQuery.noConflict();

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        fun1();
        //jquery stuff
        fun2();
    });
})(jQuery);

function fun1(){
    //stuff/jQuery code/ call other functions
}

function fun2(){
    //stuff/jQuery code/ call other functions
}
```

Comment: The important here is to first include jQuery library, then have a script block with the noConflict(), THEN include any prototype libraries.

Comment: First of all thank you for replying :)
The way the scripts are loaded is fixed and can't be changed, as i can only edit my module and not the whole page.
Nevertheless, despite prototype being loaded before jquery and jquery.noConflict, it works in ff, chrome, safari. :s

Comment: Does the prototype code work? I would think any prototype code would stop working if it was loaded in after the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix this, for IE8 (which was the only one with the problem) and other browsers was to put jQuery and the noConflict() call in the head **immediately** after initializing the other library. Like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/prototype.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>`

... followed by any other scripts that use either jQuery or Prototype.